# Do while loop in SAS

Tags: loops, sas, do-while

I am referring the [SAS documentation page](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/p1awxgleif5wlen1pja0nrn6yi6i.htm) to understand the difference between `DO while` and `DO until` loops in `SAS`. While referring this document, I came to a conclusion that whenever I used DO while loop, the inequality of while statement should always less than (or less than or equal). The inequality cannot be greater than (or greater than or equal).

The reason is follows. When I ran this code:

```
data _null_;
n=0;
   do while(n<5);
      put n=;
      n+1;
   end;
run;
```

I got the output as `0,1,2,3,4.`

But When I ran this code, I got nothing.

```
data _null_;
n=0;
   do while(n>5);
      put n=;
      n+1;
   end;
run;
```

Is my conclusion correct, or am I missing something?

Thank you
[1](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/p1awxgleif5wlen1pja0nrn6yi6i.htm):

Comment: Didn't you want to use DO UNTIL() in the second step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really whether you use > or <.  But the logic of what to test is reversed.  With DO WHILE() you execute the loop when the condition is TRUE.  With DO UNTIL() you continue executing when the condition is FALSE.

```
11   data _null_;
12     do while(n<5);
13       put n @;
14       n+1;
15     end;
16   run;

0 1 2 3 4
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


17   data _null_;
18     do until(n>=5);
19       put n @;
20       n+1;
21     end;
22   run;

0 1 2 3 4
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

The other big difference is when the test is made.  With DO WHILE() the test is before the loop starts.  With DO UNTIL() it is after the loop finishes.  So with DO UNTIL() the code always executes at least once.

Note your example is more easily done using an iterative DO loop instead.

```
6    data _null_;
7      do n=0 to 4;
8        put n @;
9      end;
10   run;

0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  In my second example, when n=0, the condition of the while statement (n>5) does not satisfy. so the loop will terminate. So does this mean that the inequality should be always >? I cannot think of any counter example for Do while with the greater than condition, other than the infinite iteration.  Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Trivial example is when you are counting down instead of counting up.